# Get callback when div is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, angular, events

I am trying to mimic android's expandable toolbar in angular component.

I hav html codes like

```
<div (scroll)="someScroll($event)">
  <div class="toolbar"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

toolbar div is having height of `70px` and remaining height is taken by body div. Since the outer div is not having any overflowing content I am not getting any scroll event callback so that I initiate expansion of toolbar div.

I tried with mouse wheel event I am getting that callback but with that data I am not able to derive anything. Also in mdn it is written `wheel` event is deprecated.

So how should I proceed with? If any sources you have please share it so that I can give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to have is `Directive` which can capture those mouse `wheel up event/ mouse wheel down` events values into your controller.

**HTML:**

```
   <h1>Wheel Directive Demo
    <div wheel style="height:1000px;background-color:green">
        <input type="text" value=""/>
    SCROLL MOUSE
   </div>
```

**Typescript :**
Create new directive by name `wheel.directive.ts`

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[wheel]'
})
export class WheelDirective {
  i: number = 1;
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) { }

      @HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMousewheel(event) {
        if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
          event.srcElement.style.setProperty('transition', 'all 200ms ease-in')
          event.srcElement.style.setProperty('transform', "scale(" + this.i + 1 + ")")
        }
        if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
          event.srcElement.style.setProperty('transition', 'all 200ms ease-out')
          event.srcElement.style.setProperty('transform', +"scale(" + this.i - 1 + ")")
        }
      }
    }
```

In **AppModule.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { WheelDirective } from './wheel.directive'
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, WheelDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Please find the working StackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnkryg).

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to show here? I mean output.

Comment: In the directive `onMousewheel(event)` event it all the relevent mouse wheel values can be captured

Comment: @Sela Can you explain your answer how will it help in my case? I can capture wheel event in component's template too, how is directive different from that?

Answer (score 0):

wheelDelta had been removed from wheelevent, you have to switch to deltaY/deltaX